# i want to replace default color code inside span, to new generated color code

Tags: javascript, colors, project

> **Code to generate random colors then displaying as background of the body. I want to replace default span text with newly generated color-code**

```js
// variables 

const hex = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];

const Color = document.querySelector('.color');

const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let hexColor = '#';
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    hexColor += hex[RandomNumber()];
  }
  Color.textContent = hexColor;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = hexColor;
  //   console.log(hexColor);
});

// random number generator 
const RandomNumber = () => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * hex.length);
};
```

```html
<h2>Color Flipper</h2>

<div class="bg-color">
  Background Color : //class of color
  <span class="color"></span>#775bd6
</div>
<div class="btn">Click Me</div>
```

Comment: At the moment your span text is outside the span... Your code works regardless.

Comment: As Andy correctly stated, your code does exactly what you want it to do; the problem is that the "default span text" isn't inside the span.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's so stupid of me not seeing this stupid error.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const hex = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];

 const Color = document.querySelector('.color');

 const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

 btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let hexColor = '#';
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
     hexColor += hex[randomNumber()];
  }
 document.getElementById('colortext').innerText = hexColor;
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = hexColor;
      console.log(hexColor);
  });
   
  function randomNumber() {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * hex.length);
  }
```

```html
<body>
<h2>Color Flipper</h2>

<div class="bg-color">
<span class="color"><p id="colortext"></p></span>
</div>
<button class="btn">Click Me</button>
```

Here's what I think you wanted :)

Comment: All this does is introduce an unnecessary element to the HTML. `Color` already points to the `span` element.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the cleanest way. Use `innerText` property. `textContent` is also legitimate, just not as clear imho. Your code was actually working, but html comments are not defined by `//` and therefore was putting the value after the comment.

```js
// variables 

const hex = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];

const Color = document.querySelector('.color');

const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let hexColor = '#';
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    hexColor += hex[RandomNumber()];
  }
  Color.textContent = hexColor;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = hexColor;
  //Color.innerText = hexColor;
  //   console.log(hexColor);
});

// random number generator 
const RandomNumber = () => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * hex.length);
};
```

```html
<h2>Color Flipper</h2>

<div class="bg-color">
  Background Color :
  <span class="color"></span>
</div>
<div class="btn">Click Me</div>
```